# PhpStorm code style: align function parentheses

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

How to fix this?

Before (exactly what is needed):

[image]

After (what I get when formatting the code):

[image]

```
$response->assertOk()
        ->assertJson(fn(AssertableJson $json) =>
            $json->has('data', fn($json) =>
                $json->whereType('id', 'integer')
                    ->whereType('created_at', 'string')
                    ->whereType('updated_at', 'string')
                    ->whereType('snils', 'string')
                    ->has('passport', fn($json) =>
                        $json->whereType('id', 'integer')
                            ->whereType('created_at', 'string')
                            ->whereType('updated_at', 'string')
                            ->whereType('series', 'string|null')
                            ->whereType('number', 'string|null')
                            ->whereType('lastName', 'string|null')
                            ->whereType('firstName', 'string|null')
                            ->whereType('middleName', 'string|null')
                            ->whereType('gender', 'string|null')
                            ->whereType('birthDate', 'string|null')
                            ->whereType('request_data', 'array|null')
                        )
                    ->whereType('request_data', 'array|null')
                    ->etc()
        )
        );
```

added copy code

Comment: Please provide your "before" code as a text -- so it can be copy-pasted for formatting testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution to my problem

[image]